# How to force restful responses in json?

Tags: yii2

I want to add some api to my Yii2 site. Api must be only in json. I don't want to set `Accept: application/json` headers for each request. I can set  `'response' => ['format' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON]` in application configuration but it breaks all pages. Also my api function returns data in xml.

I tried to use `rest\ActiveRecord` for my purposes. Maybe I do it's wrong. What I want.

To have my Yii2 based site with some api acсessed through `https://example.com/api/controller/action`. In project I want to see folder `controllers/api` which contains my controllers. Controllers must use standard `\yii\db\ActiveRecord` based models. Also controllers input paramaters only in json body or as part url and output data only in json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to set the following code in the controller's action somewhere before return or in beforeAction() method:

```
\Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
```

also since Yii 2.0.11 there is a dedicated asJson() method to return a response in JSON format:

```
return $this->asJson($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

The more elegant solution is to use [`yii\filters\ContentNegotiator`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-contentnegotiator).
When the `Accept` header is missing `ContentNegotiator` assumes it allows any type and send response in first format defined in its `$formats` property. If the requested format is not among accepted formats the content negotiator will throw `yii\web\NotAcceptableHttpException` and app will respond with http status `406 Not Acceptable`.

You can add it in your controller in `behaviors()` method like this:

```php
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\filters\ContentNegotiator',
            'formats' => [
                'application/json' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

If your controller extends `yii\rest\Controller` it already has the `ContentNegotiator` filter added among its behaviors. You only need to limit allowed formats like this:

```php
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['contentNegotiator']['formats'] = [
        'application/json' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
    ];
    return $behaviors;
}
```

Using `ContentNegotiator` instead of explicitly forcing the `JSON` format in `beforeAction()` will allow for easier addition of other formats if they are needed in future.